# I try running an SFML app but MobaXTerm prints Setting Vertical Sync not supported

Tags: c++, sfml, wsl-2

I'm using WSL2 on MobaXTerm, i'm on Windows 11, and but i can't run this simple SFML code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Using

```
g++ main.o -o sfml-app -L<sfml-install-path>/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

the code compiles correctly. I've added the following lines of code at the end of the .bashrc file:

```
export DISPLAY="$(/sbin/ip route | awk '/default/ { print $3 }'):0"
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
```

but MobaXTerm prints the following errors:
`Setting vertical sync not supported` and `X connection to <some ip adress>:0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown)`

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. It seems to be an issue with MobaXterm: when running from a WSL terminal, the program works as expected.

The issue is also present when running `glxgears` from MobaXterm: it freezes.